# MS Access SQL Running Total

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am scratching my head because I can't figure out how to create a running sum in MS Access, I tried an IIF statement, a DSUM statement and a subquery (Which is my preferred option)

Very simply, I've got a list of soccer teams, the dates of their games and the points he collects in each game and I want to create a running total.

My query isn't calculating the running sum as it should, it's just calculating the current game.

Below is my attempted code, can anyone help?

```
SELECT Team, FORMAT(mDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") AS Match_Date, Pts, 
SUM(IIF(FORMAT(mDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") <= FORMAT(mDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"),Pts)) AS Total_Pts
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT home_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals > away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND home_team = "Arsenal"  
UNION  
SELECT away_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals < away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND away_team = "Arsenal")  AS Filter ORDER BY 2 DESC)  AS Test
GROUP BY Team, FORMAT(mDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"), Pts
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Do not format dates to strings and compare such strings as if they were dates.

Then: In order to be able to join the `UNION` query to itself, the query has to be written twice, each with it's own alias. One of the queries will be used for the current game record, the other one to build the running sum of the points. The `Team` on both sides of the join have to be equal and the `mDate` of the "running" query has to be less than or equal to the `mDate` of the current game. Since the records of the first part of the `UNION` differ from the records of the second part, you can use `UNION ALL` to speed up the query a little:

```
SELECT Games.Team, Games.mDate, Games.Pts, SUM(Runnings.Pts) AS Total_Pts
FROM
(
    SELECT home_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals > away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts
    FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND home_team = "Arsenal"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT away_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals < away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts
    FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND away_team = "Arsenal"
) AS Games
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT home_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals > away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts
    FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND home_team = "Arsenal"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT away_team AS Team, match_date AS mDate, IIF(home_goals < away_goals,3,IIF(home_goals = away_goals,1,0)) AS Pts
    FROM A WHERE league = "Premiership" AND season = "2016 - 2017" AND away_team = "Arsenal"
) AS Runnings ON Games.Team = Runnings.Team AND Games.mDate >= Runnings.mDate
GROUP BY Games.Team, Games.mDate, Games.Pts
ORDER BY Games.Team, Games.mDate;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a million, I really appreciate the help.